# ArcGIS 10.2 Python-addin Zipfile locked

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I made a Python-Addin-Button with the function to create a zip. Everything works fine, but after creating the zip-file, the zipfile is locked, when the mxd-Project is open. Any suggestions why I can't open or delete the zipfile?

Here my script:

```
    import sys, os, arcpy, zipfile, traceback, pythonaddins
    from arcpy import *

    class CreateZIP(object):
        """Implementation for Python_Addins_addin.button (Button)"""
        def __init__(self):
            self.enabled = True
            self.checked = False
        def onClick(self):
            arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
            mxdpath = mxd.filePath
            inWorkspace = os.path.dirname(mxdpath)
            outWorkspace = inWorkspace
            arcpy.env.workspace = inWorkspace
            outzip = zipfile.ZipFile(outWorkspace+"\Arch_Data.zip","a",zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
            infolder = os.path.join(inWorkspace,"DATA")
            path = os.path.normpath(infolder)
            for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
                for file in filenames:
                    if not file.endswith(".lock"):
                            outzip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file),os.path.join(os.path.basename(path),
                                                              os.path.join(dirpath, file)[len(path)+len(os.sep):]))
            outzip.close()                
            z = zipfile.ZipFile("Arch_Data.zip","a")
            z.write("README.txt")
            outzip.close()
```

Comment: I call your attention to the fact it is not necessary to use the workspace.  os.getcwd() = os.path.dirname(mxdpath). Also if you have not pre-registered in your mxd, the path will be empty. In this case mxdpath=u"" because MapDocument is in memory outWorkspace+"\Arch_Data.zip" can be directly Arch_Data.zip if you create zip in same folder as your document because it use os.getcwd() as basepath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you open zipfile twice and clause only one

```
        outzip.close()                
        z = zipfile.ZipFile("Arch_Data.zip","a")
        z.write("README.txt")
        # outzip.close()# This is Not Good!!!
        z.close()  # Check with this
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help and suggestions. As well I added a check to test, if the readme, that I append to the zipfolder exists. Now the Add-in-button works fine:

```
def onClick(self):
        try:
            arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
            mxdpath = mxd.filePath
            inWorkspace = os.path.dirname(mxdpath)
            outzip = zipfile.ZipFile("Arch_Data.zip","a",zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
            infolder = os.path.join(inWorkspace,"DATA")
            path = os.path.normpath(infolder)
            for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
                for file in filenames:
                    if not file.endswith(".lock"):
                            outzip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file),os.path.join(os.path.basename(path),
                                                                  os.path.join(dirpath, file)[len(path)+len(os.sep):]))
            outzip.close()                
            z = zipfile.ZipFile("Arch_Data.zip","a")
            if os.path.isfile("README.txt"):  
                z.write("README.txt")
                z.close()
            else:
                pythonaddins.MessageBox("Don't forget to add the readme.","Info",0)
```